# How to use INSERT INTO SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with IF statement

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

Here I am trying to do **on duplicate key update** record in MySQL in a given condition.
Let's say I have a table called "Item" and another table called "Item_backup" which has a set of backup records that should be inserted to the original "Item" table. The structures of the two tables are same in both the tables.

When the data records are inserting if there are any **duplicate keys** then I need to check the insert_date column and the record should be updated only if the insert_date column in "Item" table is less than the insert_date column in the "Item_backup" table.

The query that I used is,

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (item_number, price, quantity, insert_date)
SELECT ib.item_number, ib.price, ib.quantity, ib.insert_date 
FROM ITEM_backup ib
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
item_number = IF(@is_a_new_record := insert_date < ib.insert_date, ib.item_number, item_number),
price = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.price, price),
quantity = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.quantity, quantity),
insert_date = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.insert_date, insert_date);
```

Now an error is getting like this,
**"SQL Error: Column 'insert_date' in field list is ambiguous"**

Can anyone point out what is wrong with this query?

Comment: Please add your table definition for item (including keys)

Comment: CREATE TABLE ITEM (
  item_number int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Item number',
  price int(15) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Item price',
  quantity int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quantity',
  insert_date int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last inserted date',
  PRIMARY KEY (item_number)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Item';

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the right answer.

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (item_number, price, quantity, insert_date)
SELECT ib.item_number, ib.price, ib.quantity, ib.insert_date 
FROM ITEM_backup ib
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
item_number = IF(@is_a_new_record := ITEM.insert_date < ib.insert_date, ib.item_number, ITEM.item_number),
price = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.price, ITEM.price),
quantity = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.quantity, ITEM.quantity),
insert_date = IF(@is_a_new_record, ib.insert_date, ITEM.insert_date);
```